How do I pass user data into Selenium scraper deployed on Google Cloud Functions
I am trying to set up a simple script on Google Cloud functions which logs onto my google account using a directory containing my user data. I have tried this in Selenium, but a solution with any Python library is fine. This is my main.py being deployed:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import os

def testScraper(event, context):
    driver = None
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--headless=old")
    user_data_path = "UserData"
    options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir={user_data_path}")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    if os.path.exists(user_data_path):
        print("The folder exists")

    if os.access(user_data_path, os.R_OK) and os.access(user_data_path, os.W_OK):
        print("Read and write permissions are available.")
    else:
        print("Insufficient permissions for the profile directory.")

    driver.get('https://myaccount.google.com/')
    time.sleep(5)
    print(driver.current_url)

To access my user data, I have copied over the file 'UserData' (300MB) into a zip file along with my main.py and requirements.txt and used Source code:ZIP Upload in the following structure:
main.py
requirements.txt
UserData/
  ├── Default/
  └── ...

When I try running the script, I get the messages "The folder exists" and "Read and write permissions are available.", but I am unable to log into my account because the print statement returns https://www.google.com/account/about/?hl=en-US (which is where you get directed if you are not logged in)
I have verified that the chromedriver version matches the chrome version, and also that the user data folder is working by running an identical script on my local machine. It's worth mentioning I tried the method of uploading the UserData folder to Google Cloud Storage buckets, and then downloading that directory to /tmp/UserData but that didn't work either.
It just seems that options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir= works in a different way on Google Cloud Functions compared to locally. Is there anything else I should be doing?
